# Вывод объемного текста. Как лучше?

Tags: java, android, оптимизация, textview, текст

Как лучше всего сделать вывод огромного* текста из txt файла? Насчёт чтения из файла я знаю как делать, а вот куда выводить не знаю, мне кажется, что стандартный textview просто повиснет.

P.S. Жалко что в Android нет виндосовского Memo :)

*Огромный - 100'000-300'000 слов

Comment: а надо ли выводить весь сразу? может разбить на "страницы" и использовать какой-нибудь `RecyclerView` ?

Comment: Желательно бы сразу